# TYPO3 backend user how hide subpages

Tags: typo3

I have TYPO3 9.5

I want to set db_mountpoints for a backend user group: only 4 pages.
Some of pages have subpages and the users of group can see the subpages.
I don't want that the group to see the subpages.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could change the access to pages using the backend module "System" -> **"Access"**.
there you can change the owner and group of pages, and also which rights owner, group, everyone has for these pages.

Make sure new pages have the right group and rights on creation with appropiate default settings in page TSconfig.

```
TCEMAIN.permissions {
    // group for new pages:
    groupid = 1
    // access rights: 
    user = 31
    group = 19
    everybody = 1
}
```

The rights are bit coded:

```
 1 = show page
 2 = edit page
 4 = delete page
 8 = create pages
16 = edit content
```